# Why does my THD-value not converge in simulation of rectifier circuit?

Tags: circuit-design, simulation, rectifier, multisim, total-harmonic-distortion

I'm trying to simulate a FWR - circuit with an RC-load. In doing so, I want to analyze the THD-value of the circuit.
[image]

In the end, I've tried changing the FFT-points, increasing and decreasing the harmonic numbers, changing the resolution frequency, but withour any result. The circuit is correct, since it outputs a signal on the oscilloscope that's expected.

I tried the distortion analyzer on simpler circuits aswell, such as a HWR - circuit, and succeeded in calculating the THD there without any issues.

What's going on here really?

Answer (score 2):

Here is what you should observe.  (Don't know what simulator you are using).

> I tried the distortion analyzer on simpler circuits aswell, such as a HWR - circuit, and succeeded in calculating the THD there without any issues.

You have no issues because the ground is "well" wired.

In full wave rectifier (FWR), the ground is wired at the common of R-C and D1-D3 and not at the negative part of generator.

NB: the generator should be left "floating". The "ground" is common wire of D1 and D3.

[image]

And harm(vo) should be:

[image]

THD should be found as usual, applying "definition" (did not made).

Comment: (What is \$V_2\$ about?)

Comment: Just a DC add. Does not matter here. It is equal to zero.

Comment: @Antonio51 ohhh okay so that’s the problem. Can I ask why the ground is wired at a different place? Why would the choice of ground ”position” matter between a HWR and a FWR? Also, thank you very much for spotting what I did wrong!!

Comment: Update: when I recreate your circuit, I get a non zero THD that does converge when grounding at the negative part of the generator. When I ground like you do, my distortion doesn't converge and shows --E-- once again. This is very weird :/

Comment: When using a bridge (FWR with no center point), you must use the low point of load as ground. NB: you should use always this point as ground.